# typescript import notation "import type {SomeType} from "../.." -- with no filename

Tags: typescript

I saw this unfamiliar `import type` notation [here](https://github.com/ajv-validator/ajv/blob/master/spec/types/json-schema.spec.ts)

```
import _Ajv from "../ajv"
import type {JSONSchemaType} from "../.."
import type {SchemaObject} from "../.."
```

Is it a mistake or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, the distinctions between the `import type` and `import` syntaxes have nothing to do with module paths. They are orthogonal concepts.

Now, onto the question of paths:

The paths in the following code,

```
import _Ajv from "../ajv"
import type {JSONSchemaType} from "../.."
import type {SchemaObject} from "../.."
```

all resolve to file names.

This resolution is based on common JavaScript package and module layout conventions that TypeScript incorporates and follows.

For example, under `--moduleResolution node` the module specifier `"../.."` resolves to a file located two directories above the importing file and named `index.{ts|d.ts|js}`, I.e. `"../../in/index.ts"`.

In other words, importing from a directory path is equivalent to importing from the file named index in that directory.

Answer (score 1):

It's importing from the `index.ts` file

Imagine next structure:

```
src/components
src/components/comp1.ts
src/components/comp2.ts
src/components/index.ts
```

Where `index.ts` simply reexports all from `comp1.ts` and `comp2.ts` like here

```
import Component1 from './comp1';
export {Component1}
```

Now you can import from index file without naming index file

```
import {Component1} from './components';
```